# CTRL-F search on page with significant text freezes IE11 in Edge Mode, but not IE7 Emulation mode

Tags: html, xml, internet-explorer-11

I've got a very simple page on which we're rendering out a very large (~32k row) XML file rendered as plain text inside a `pre` tag. The markup that ends up being displayed in the browser is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="IE=11.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
</head>
<body>
    <pre> /* 32,000 lines of XML, not shown here */ </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

The typical workflow on this page would be that a user would open this dialog and use CTRL-F to search for content within the XML. On our system today, where IE runs in IE7 emulation mode, this works fine. The find is responsive, and users are able to search. however, when we change the browser's rendering mode to Edge mode, IE11 hangs as soon as anything is input into the "find" dialog.

Does anyone know why IE11 would perform so much poorer at such a simple operation than IE7, and can anyone suggest a workaround? Is there a better way to present this large amount of XML as a searchable body of text, without causing the browser to choke on it? I understand it's not an ideal way to search that much text, but it worked fine in IE7 emulation mode and it just seems strange that IE11 would work so dramatically worse.